# Detecting GPRS network availability in android

Tags: android, networking, gprs, ksoap

I am using Ksoap to call my web service & i display a progressDialog while i get the response. But if i enter a area where there is no network, it continues searching for the network (The progress dialog doesnt stop.. i need 2 ForceStop my app ). I have caught Exception in my Ksoap calling method.. but no exception is thrown...

cud any1 help how do i fix this ..

---

This dint solve my issue. It always returns true for isConnected(). Finally i am now using below code in my Ksoap Class (with  ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.4-jar-with-dependencies ) to detect timeout, which i guess is helping me out. Need 2 do some more testing.

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransportSE;
 int TimeOut=180000;
 androidHttpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL,TimeOut);
 androidHttpTransportSE.call(soap_action, envelope);

SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
 reply = response.toString();

any 1 having a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the ConnectivityManager (Connectivity Service) to give more information on if the data network is available or not.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo()

getActiveNetworkInfo() method would give you more information on the current network connected to.

Comment: also you need to add a permission in the manifest for this one. i think it was read network info or something like that.